# Redirect to Login Route from Application Route if user is not authenticated

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm using ember-cli-simple-auth 1.0.1.

My doubt now is how can i force redirect to /login if the a user tries to access the application route / if he is not log in?

Answer (score 2):

I would set up an `AuthenticatedRoute` which mixes in `ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin` and has all protected routes nested within it.  And then set up a `LoginRoute` which mixes in `ember-simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin`.

```
application:
  - login
  - authenticated
    - all protected routes
```

Mixing in one or the other of those directly into `ApplicationRoute` wouldn't really work.  However you should mix `ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin` into it to automatically handle `authenticationSucceeded` and `invalidationSucceeded` actions.

See [github](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) and the [mixin docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/ApplicationRouteMixin.html).

It will default to redirecting to `/login`, and you can configure this in `config/environment.js`.  [Docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html).

```
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  authenticationRoute: 'signin'
};
```